# influxdb histogram flux query with filter

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

I'm using influxdb 2 to store a time series db of water stations. The points are something like:

```py
from influxdb_client import Point

Point("station").tag("id", station_id).field("pressure", 0).time(datetime.now())
Point("station").tag("id", station_id).field("pressure", 1).time(datetime.now())
Point("station").tag("id", station_id).field("pressure", 1).time(datetime.now())
Point("station").tag("id", station_id).field("pressure", 3).time(datetime.now())
Point("station").tag("id", station_id).field("pressure", 2).time(datetime.now())
Point("station").tag("id", station_id).field("pressure", 0).time(datetime.now())
```

So the pressure varies from `0` to `3`.

Hon can I retrive a histogram filtered by `station_id` using `[0, 1, 2, 3]` as bins for pressure using **Flux**?